# mod_rewrite - writing regular expression for clean url and unclean url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

If i have a mod rewrite code as following:

```
RewriteRule ^/(\w+)/?$ index.php?id=$1
```

I'm new to mod-rewrites and i was wondering if a user enters a clean url instead of a unclean, e.g.

http://example.com/1000/

into browser rather than

http://example.com/index.php?id=1000

will i still be able to request the $_GET[] variable of 1000?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Should work.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?id=$1           [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Aiden You should test all answers to decide whether they work or not. Your rule doesn't work because it has a leading `/` in the regex, so the condition will never match. On the other hand, the way to do it is as it is in this answer, to prevent loops and to define a RewriteBase. ¿What happens with this answer, did it work for you or you just didn't like it at first sight?

Comment: Hey Felipe, i just reinstalled xampp and change apache config, your code works great thankyou very much

Answer (score -1):

I use `RewriteRule ^/(\w+)/?$ index.php?id=$1` just as you have ...  And I assure you it works .. Have you enabled Mod Rewrites?

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i have checked apache handlers and it says its mod_rewrite but when i try it nothing works, i also changed the AllowOverride None to All and restarted apache several times, maybe i have a problem with my installation on the localhost?